# Is there an enumeration of finitely presented groups?

Tags: group-theory, free-groups, combinatorial-group-theory

I know that the general word problem is undecidable, but is there an effective enumeration of presentations all finitely presented groups generated by $n$ elements in which each isomorphism class of a group appears exactly once?

I have no idea of how to tackle this problem, and I'm motivated by the fact that isomorphism classes of path connected covering maps $E \to \bigvee_n S^1$ correspond precisely to subgroups of the free group of $n$ elements. So answering the previous question solves the one about covering maps too.

Comment: There is continuum of isomorphism classes of 2-generated groups.

Comment: @MoisheKohan You're completely right! I missed that as I'm too used to a finite amount of relations in a presentation. This makes my second goal unobtainable, but I'll edit the question to restrict it finitely presented n-generated groups since it seems interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the isomorphism problem for finitely presented groups is undecidable, there can be no such enumeration, at least for $n \ge 2$.

If there were such an enumeration $G_1,G_2,\ldots,G_n,\ldots$  then I could solve the isomorphism problem as follows. Given a finite presentation on $n$ generators, attempt to construct isomorphisms between the group defined by this presentation and the groups $G_1,G_2,\ldots,G_n,\ldots$ in parallel. Eventually an isomorphism with exactly one of the groups $G_i$ would be found.

Comment: How do you know a putative isomorphism works? Maybe $f$ seems to be an isomorphism between $A$ and $B$, but two words $a,a'$ that look currently distinct in $A$ wind up getting collapsed later on while their images $f(a),f(a')$ don't.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Two groups defined by finite presentations are isomorphic if and only if one can be transformed to the other by a sequence of Tietze transformations, so you can just systematically try all such sequences. There are more efficient ways of searching for an isomorphism in practice, but it becomes rapidly less practical as the number of generators increases.

Comment: Sorry, I was confused by the original version of the question which asked about finitely *generated* groups (and for some reason I assumed that the OP meant "recursively presented groups").